# How do I update sub document with "save" function in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My questions is bit naive but I could not find an answer after searching everywhere.

I have a schema of `user`

```
name: {type:String},
relations: [{
    entity: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    year: {type:Number}
}]
```

I want to update the year of a user with `relations.entity` = R1

I am able to update it with an `update` function

```
var toupdate = {}
toupdate["relations.$.year"] = 1900;

User.update({'relations.entity': 'R1'},{"$set": toupdate},
    function(err,results){
    // console.log(results);
});
```

While this works well, I want to use `.save()` method as I have other fields that are already being updated above.

```
User.find({_id:"myid"},function(err,user){
    user.name = "my new name";

    // find the relation matching the relations.entity = "R1"

    user.save(function(err,results){
        // send my results returned
    });
})
```

How do I write the logic before calling `save()`?

Comment: `relations` is an array of objects, not a single object. It does not have a field `_id`. The only ID I see is coming from `entity`.

Comment: It does have an `_id` field, Looks like mongoose is creating it though not defined in schema.

Comment: You just need to find array and update the value at index. Something like `User.find({_id:"myid",'relations.entity': 'R1'},function(err,user){
    user.name = "my new name";
    index = user.relations.findIndex((relation => relation.entity == 'R1'));
    user.relations[index].year = 1900;
    user.save(function(err,results){
    });
})`

Comment: @Veeram  I get an error saying `relations is not defined` for `user.relations.findIndex` however when I do `console.log(user.relations)` we can se them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var year = 1900;
var entity = "R1"

User.find({_id:"myid"},function(err,user){
    user.name = "my new name";
    if ( user.relations && Object.prototype.toString.call( user.relations ) === '[object Array]' ) {
       user.relations.forEach( (relation, index , relations) => { 
          if(relation.entity === entity  ) {
             relations[index].year = year;
          }
       })
    }
    // find the relation matching the relations.entity = "R1"

    user.save(function(err,results){
        // send my results returned
    });
})
```

For multi relation update you can change entity to array and using indexOf to update the year.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.findOne({_id:"myid"},function(err,user){
  user.name = "my new name";
  var tmp = user.relations;
  _.forEach(tmp,function(aObj){
    if(aObj.entity == 'R'){
      aObj.year = 1900;
    }
  });
  user.relations = tmp;
  user.save(function(err,results){
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findOne({_id:"myid"})
.deepPopulate('relations.entity')
.exec(function(err,user) {
user.name = "my new name";
var tmp = user.relations;
 _.forEach(tmp,function(aObj){
if(search variable path == 'R'){
aObj.year = 1994;
 }
});
user.relations = tmp;
user.save(function(err,results){
console.log("results",results);
});
});
```